# az cli login session scope to process

Tags: powershell, jenkins, azure-cli

In PowerShell you can do the following:

```
$result = Connect-AzAccount `
  -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId `
  -TenantId $TenantId `
  -Credential $credential `
  -ContextName $contextName `
  -Scope Process `
  -ServicePrincipal
```

As per the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/connect-azaccount?view=azps-5.7.0), if you specify the `-Scope Process` the Az Context will be bound to that specific PS Process.

> Determines the scope of context changes, for example, whether changes apply only to the current process, or to all sessions started by this user.

Is there any way of replicating this behaviour with `az cli`?

**My use case**
I will connect to Azure from a Jenkins job. If I start two jobs, maybe one of them will disconnect via `az logout -u <user>` and affect the other job.

I would like to isolate the `az cli` session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't personally used it yet, but according to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/15389#issuecomment-754505850) which links to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/use-cli-effectively#concurrent-builds), it should be possible using a process scoped environment variable.

Comment: This looks promising

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is not such an equivalent feature as `-Scope Process` in Azure CLI, all the available parameters here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest#az_login

[image]

Comment: :( I hope in the future there will be a feature like this. I think for the moment I will call login before any az CLI call to be sure I have a valid context. This, though might change mid-execution but I think this is the best solution atm